# Why don't the circles in this d3 example move?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to test performance when drawing and redrawing circles in d3. I don't need to transition the circles just replace the data wholesale.

I thought this snippet would do it but it doesn't.

How can I make this work?

```js
'use strict';

var w = $('#outlet').width();
var h = $('#outlet').height();

function getRandomInSVG(max) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 0 + 1)) + 0;
}

function getRandomCoord() {
 var x = getRandomInSVG(w);
 var y = getRandomInSVG(h);
 return [x, y];
}

function addRandomData(container) {
 var data = [];
 for(var index = 0; index < 5000; index++) {
  data[index] = getRandomCoord();
 }

 container.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function (d) { 
   return d[0];
  })
  .attr('cy', function (d) { 
   return d[1];
  })
  .attr('r', '1px')
  .attr('fill', 'red');
}


var svg = d3.select('#outlet')
    .append('svg:svg')
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', h);


setInterval(function() {
 console.log('add random data');
 addRandomData(svg);
}, 1000);
```

```html
  <body>
    <h1>D3 Fun!</h1>
    <div id="outlet" style="height:600px;width:600px;">
      
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have the enter pattern. To redraw you need to call the update pattern, see also http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#enter-update-exit

You have to change your addRandomData function as follows:

```
function addRandomData(container) {
    var data = [];
    for(var index = 0; index < 5000; index++) {
        data[index] = getRandomCoord();
    }

    var updateSel =  container.selectAll('circle')
        .data(data);   
    updateSel
        .enter()
        .append('circle');
    updateSel
        .attr('cx', function (d) { 
            return d[0];
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) { 
            return d[1];
        })
        .attr('r', '1px')
        .attr('fill', 'red');
}
```

Working example for your question is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ee2todev/mbeonehu/).

Comment: ah, pretty subtle difference but that's awesome. Thanks!

Comment: The enter-update-exit pattern is pretty well documented and intuitive. What is used here in addition is tha fact that after the enter pattern, the update selection contains both the update and the enter selection. That's why the setting of the attributes are also applied the first time, when the enter pattern is followed.

Comment: yep, it's the capturing of the updateSel variable, then append circles to enter, then applying attributes as three commands rather than one that seems a subtle difference to me. I need to think about it more :)

Comment: The only reason there are three commands is to reduce redundancy. You could have just two commands: container.selectAll('circle').data(data).enter().append('circle'); and container.selectAll('circle').data(data).attr(...). It's really worth fully understanding the explanation by Mike Bostock at the link I gave above. Have fun with d3!